# How do I use a Canvas texture on a 3D polygon face that is not a rectangle

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh with plane geometry that I texture with a 2D canvas element. This is working perfectly.

```
var landTexture = new THREE.Texture(land.canvas);  // animated canvas element
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: landTexture});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( this.land_width, this.land_height ), material );
landTexture.needsUpdate = true;
landObject.add(plane);
```

The 2D canvas has an animated pattern which I want to use as a texture on a pentagon instead of a plane. How do I go about texturing more complex polygons, e.g. a pentagon, with a 2D canvas texture?

Edit: how I generate the pentagon

```
var pentagon = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CircleGeometry(this.land_width, 5), material );
```

Screenshot of the animated texture on PlaneGeometry and the same texture on a CircleGeometry with 5 sides. Notice the "stretched" canvas texture on the pentagon, which is not what I want. It should fit proportionally.

[image: Example of stretched canvas texture]

Comment: Two questions: (1) Can you post the code you are using for generating a pentagon, and (2) Do you want to stretch the canvas onto the pentagon or do you want to crop a pentagon-shaped region from the canvas and use that as the texture?

Comment: I've edited my question showing how I generate the pentagon. The answer to your second question is the latter, I want to crop a pentagon-shaped region from the canvas and use that as the texture? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the UVs are already set so that code such as:

```
var grid = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/uvgrid01.jpg' );
var pentagon = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CircleGeometry(50, 5), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:grid}) );
```

when the grid is the image:

[image]

will produce an image like:

[image]

Is that what you're looking for? Then all that is left is to update the texture repeatedly, and each time this is done, set the flag to update the material.  I can go into more detail, but I would need to know how the canvas is being animated.

Comment: Ah, once I checked the canvas constraints, I realised my mistake in calculating the size to accommodate the pentagon fully. I increased the canvas size and positioned it accordingly. I guess a little XY problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JacquesCoetsee how did u figure out what size to calculate?!